# Which of these chemicals share a likeness in structure with benzodiazepines causing false-positives in urine tests?

Tags: medicinal-chemistry

Below are potential culprits:

Quetiapine, Oxcarbazepine, and Valproate feature in the current medicine regime.

Olanzapine was discontinued quite recently.

Quetiapine XR (increased to 400mg) and an increased dose of Oxcarbazepine (900mg) were quite recently added to the medicine regime.

Following that, a 5-panel urine test came out positive for benzodiazepines along with lab results confirming: 88 nanograms.

Please assume that the individual in question is honest about not ingesting any benzodiazepines.

Thank you!

Comment: Let me say that the 5-panel drug test is a preliminary immunoassay, suitable for qualitative testing. If you are sure that the result is a false-positive, you should request a better test (HPLC, GC-MS...)

Answer (score 1):

Rather depends on what structural features the assay is picking up but Quetiapine (Seroquel) certainly has similarities to benzodiazepines. Oxcarbazepine does to a lesser extent, valproate is not really a candidate.